# Create variables from array values

Tags: php, arrays

I wrote 2 functions, one that gets all folder names and saves them in an array, and a second that gets all images file names and also saves them in array.

I would like to have a loop that runs over the folder names and saves each file name array into a variable that has the same name as the folder name array value.

It is possible?

```
foreach ($folders as $folder) {

    *$foldername* = getImages($folder);
}
```

Hopefully its even possible.

UPDATE:

I'll try to explain what I want to achive...

I have an array of my folders

```
$allDirs = array
(
   'cat1' => 'category1'
   'cat2' => 'category2'
   'cat3' => 'category3'
)
```

And I would like to run loop that create an arrays for each of values and save the variable as...

```
$category1= array
(
   'img1' => 'image1.jpg'
   'img2' => 'image2.jpg'
)

$category2= array
(
   'img1' => 'image1.jpg'
   'img2' => 'image2.jpg'
)

$category3= array
(
   'img1' => 'image1.jpg'
   'img2' => 'image2.jpg'
)
```

Hopefully this is much readable  :)

Comment: Read this 3 times, but still not sure what you mean: `I would like to have a loop that run over the folder names and save each file names array into a variable that has the same name as the folder name array value.` -- could you explain?

Comment: How about `extract()` function?

Comment: @revo `extract` is used for associative arrays, it would not help the OP.

Comment: @Jessica He can use the same name as its value and key.

Comment: Which would still not solve the problem. If he had an array `['foo'=>'foo']` and used `extract`, he would then have `$foo` which held `'foo'`.

Comment: @Jessica well u mistaken

Comment: @revo really? Please show me proof of how you would use extract() to get a bunch of variables with the folder contents, as the OP has asked. I'm sure it will be marked as the answer if you can.

Comment: @Jessica It seems that I misunderstood OP :/

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($folders as $folder) {
   $$folder = getImages($folder);
}
```

It's called variable variables.

Probably not a good idea, it's hard to tell from your question, but that's how you do it.